# Open ssh session with defined title from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, centos, putty

I have a little problem with executing putty(from command line) with **-m** argument.
Please help me with this, or suggest a better way if you know one :)

The command(from "Run"):

```
putty -ssh user@machine -pw password -m C:\test.txt
```

"test.txt" command:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;'$( ifconfig | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')'\007"'
```

The problem:
**It opens the session and then closes straight away**

What does it suppose to do:
Open ssh session from command line with defined title

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't got an ssh to test it on right now but http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.security.ssh/2012-04/msg00005.html    "If you just want the window to stay open for you too look at, put
sleep 10
at the end of your script for a 10 second wait.

If you want to use the shell, use
exec /bin/bash
at the end

Shai"  http://superuser.com/questions/587629/putty-run-a-remote-command-after-login-keep-the-shell-running      http://superuser.com/questions/385715/how-do-i-choose-what-shows-up-in-putty-title-bar-from-linux

Answer (score 1):

I believe you tried to do something similar as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/385759/456414). But the thing is, the sample commands provided there are to be executed from the file on the server.

They cannot be passed as command(s) to execute using -m switch. This switch of PuTTY [is to mimic](https://superuser.com/a/708757/456414) the behavior of Linux command-line SSH client:

`ssh user@foo command`

This way ssh logs a `user` on the `foo` server, runs `command` there, and just exits. Looks like with -m PuTTY is doing exactly the same thing.

**My suggestion**

is to prepare a script on the remote server and configure PuTTY in a different way. First of all, you need to create a file with the commands you would like to run after logging in, let's call it `.title`

```
cat > ~/.title
```

Then just type, or copy and paste whatever you need there, press Ctrl+D afterwards. For now let's just test setting the title:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;PuTTY\007"
```

You can even try the above directly in terminal. If the window title of PuTTY is not changed, chances are your distribution already set [default PROMPT_COMMAND variable](http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/how-to-set-the-putty-window-title-via-script/). You can confirm that by executing the following commands in terminal

```
echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
echo -ne "\033]0;PuTTY test\007"
```

The key is to unset current value of `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable. Then the last command should set the window title to `PuTTY test`.

**My solution**

that works for me is to prepare a session in PuTTY, with ["Remote command" box in GUI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116674) set to:

```
/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.title
```

Just remember to provide the name of this session (for example: SessionName) and press "Save" button on the first page of PuTTY settings, near "Saved Sessions" list :)

Then you can start PuTTY and tell it to load this session

```
putty -load SessionName -l user -pw password
```

Yes, it's sad, but there is no command-line equivalent of "Remote command" box for a saved session. That's why one has to go over all these hurdles :(

**TL;DR version**

Assuming that you do all these steps correctly, everything should work fine:

- create `~/.title` script on the remote machine
- prepare a session with Remote command that runs Bash which will execute `~/.title`
- tell PuTTY to load prepared session upon start, specifying user and password

**Pro tip**

Instead of specifying passwords in clear text on command line (and possibly in scripts), you should learn to use SSH keys and run 'Pageant' (PuTTY authentication agent) in Windows tray.

Comment: Great first answer. Welcome to Super User.

Comment: I hoped to avoid running script on remote machine, but it seems that there is no other way.
Thanks for all who answered, I am new here so I can't vote yet :X

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got an ssh to test it on right now but http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.security.ssh/2012-04/msg00005.html
 "If you just want the window to stay open for you too look at, put sleep 10 at the end of your script for a 10 second wait. If you want to use the shell, use `exec /bin/bash` at the end. Shai"

two other links that offer some insight.

[PuTTY: Run a remote command after login & keep the shell running](https://superuser.com/questions/587629/putty-run-a-remote-command-after-login-keep-the-shell-running)

[How do I choose what shows up in PuTTY title bar from Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/385715/how-do-i-choose-what-shows-up-in-putty-title-bar-from-linux)

**Added by barlop**

the following isn't using putty, it uses openssh in cygwin The `a.a` file could contain ls  or commands to change the prompt. It's local.

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 "cat | bash" < a.a
```

related , see answer I just posted to - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments/208952#208952

Comment: First of all, "exec /bin/bash" helped indeed. Now, it doesn't close the session BUT It doesn't execute "PROMPT_COMMAND=..." that I wrote in description. The weird thing is that it works with different commands. For example: if "test.txt" was: 
"ls -a 
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo... exec 
/bin/bash"

all works but not PROMPT command

Comment: @igor what if you put the PROMPT_COMMAND after the exec?

Comment: same result :(
It displays ls -a(I took it just for the example), but doesn't execute PROMPT

Comment: Important to say that the command does work on opened session.
I tried with "-t" like it suggested in the link that you sent, but unfortunately same results.

Comment: ok now I have ssh on a machine to test.. and the ./bin/bash  or exec /bin/bash just kind of crashes it, it doesn't cause a prompt to appear.  I'll keep my "answer" here as it was something to try at least, and maybe the comments may be of interest to some.

Comment: I still will be really glad to find a way to avoid scripting on destination machine, just with simple "run" command.

Comment: @igor   see my edit to my answer, it may help or be of interest